# Node.js FS write a somewhat large image file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

So to solve the canvas `toDataUrl` security issue, I am going to request an image on the server and write it to my server to serve the client my hosted version of the image.

I am requesting images that have the proper rights.

```
var imageId = shortid.generate();

fs.writeFile('./externalImages/'+imageId+'.jpg', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/LeBron_James_3409937543.jpg', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

The image saves but is usually corrupted.

I assume I need to create a stream or buffer the data before completion, because I think it's finishing before all data is written.

My question is how do I create a stream or buffer so that the whole file is written then finish is called?

Comment: You are not writing the contents of the URL, but the URL itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) is a string or buffer, so you are actually writing the string `'http://url'` which results in the image being corrupted.  Instead, you want to pipe the response of a request to that url to the file, e.g.

```
http.get(url, function (res) {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./externalImages/'+imageId+'.jpg'));
});
```

Comment: Technically, it doesn't result in an image being corrupted. It just results in creating a text (not image) file with a ".jpg" extension containing the url.

Comment: Additionally, if this stuff isn't cacheable, you can pipe it straight to your client and avoid the disk entirely.